# Geb & Spock: Close Browser Between Each Test

Tags: spock, geb

I need to close my browser between each test.  Geb creates the browser for me, so I am under the impression that Geb should shut down the driver between each test.  However it doesn't.  Here's a structure and part of the GebConfig.groovy.

```
test_automation
-functional
--src
---test
---groovy
----spec
-----Test Locations
---resources
----GebConfig.groovy
```

GebConfig.groovy

```
waiting {
    timeout = 20
}

environments {
    chrome {
        driver = {
            System.setProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver', 'src/test/resources/chromedriver')
            new ChromeDriver()
        }
    }

    firefox {
        driver = { new FirefoxDriver() }
    }
}
```

I've extended GebSpec to CommonGebSpec and here are multiple things I've tried:

CommonGebSpec.groovy

```
def setup() {
    resetBrowser()
    getBrowser()
}

def cleanup() {
    browser.close()
    browser.quit()
}
______________________________

def cleanup() {
    browser.clearCookies()
}
______________________________

def cleanup() {
    resetBrowser()
}
```

I've tried those specifically and may variations thereof.  Anyone know why my browser won't close between tests?

Thanks.

Comment: Geb exits after each task. I am not sure whether it can exit after each test!

Comment: May I ask what is the reason for wanting to restart the browser after each test? Do you want to restart it after each test in a particular spec or each test globally?

Comment: Each test globally.  The way the application works is if we run into some sort of error, a 404 page appears that doesn't have a logout.  So, the user's credentials are still cached, if we start running the new task we have some conflicts.  Instead of working around that mess, to make sure we start in a clean state, it's just easier to restart the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example with [its associated thread](http://markmail.org/search/list%3aorg.codehaus.geb#query%3alist%3Aorg.codehaus.geb+page:1+mid%3ad4gi4xfcn7czzc4r+state%3aresults) on the Geb user list. It's overkill probably for answering your question, but it shows how to quit and start a new browser instance for each test.

Note that you'll have to quit() the browser yourself after each test.

```
import geb.spock.GebSpec
import pages.RememberMePage
import spock.lang.*
import utils.PageHelper
import org.openqa.selenium.Cookie

class RememberMeLoginSpec extends GebSpec {
    @Shared cookieName = "remember-me"
    @Shared cookieValue = "initial"

    def "login user with remember me checked and close browser"() {
        given: 
        PageHelper.login(browser, "userOne", "password1!", true, false)
        cookieValue = driver.manage().getCookieNamed(cookieName).getValue()
        browser.close()
    }

    def "user opens browser"() {
        when: "cookie is set and user is logged in"
        browser.config.cacheDriver = false
        browser.driver = browser.config.driver
        RememberMePage rememberMePage = browser.to RememberMePage
        // navigate to a page before setting cookie to avoid 
        // https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=728
        go "pageOne"
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie(cookieName, cookieValue)
        driver.manage().addCookie(cookie)
        // navigate to new page to "login" user
        go "pageTwo"

        then: "username appears in greeting and page requiring full authentication shows login modal"
        rememberMePage.navigation.greetingText.text().endsWith("userOne")
        rememberMePage.loginModal.loginModal.present

        cleanup:
        browser.quit()
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was restarting the browser incorrectly trying to call getBrowser()
To simplify it:
    def setup() {
        browser.config.cacheDriver = false
        browser.driver = browser.config.driver
    }

    def cleanup() {
        browser.quit()
    }

Comment: Exactly. Now that I've reread your question I see it says "each test." It was late in my time zone when I answered. Glad it helped.

Comment: Instead of `browser.quit()` use `browser.close()`.  Reporting is still done after the browser is closed, so an exception will be thrown otherwise.

Comment: This solution has the ugly side effect of the session being invalid after the first browser has been closed. Subsequently, no further screenshots are taken. The fact that you cannot rely on lexical execution order to feature methods has also not been considered. Maybe you want to check out [my better solution here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42073620/1082681). P.S.: It does not consider cookie handling but browser/driver handling.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having a single test in each class/file try below code:

```
 def cleanupSpec() {
    if(browser.driver){
        CachingDriverFactory.clearCache()
        browser.driver.quit()
    }
}
```

Usually if you use cleanup() method it will close the browser after first instance and subsequent tests will fail.